# I cant load the image to my page in Django. Tried anything

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I cant load the image to my page in Django. Tried anything
Tested on simple example

This is my code:

my model

```
class Head(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Test'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Text')
    img = models.ImageField(verbose_name='image')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my view

```
def show(request):
    args={}
    args['head'] = Head.objects.get()
    return render_to_response('main.html', args)
```

my urls

```
from Test import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', 'app.views.show' ),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>

<title>{{ head.title }}</title>
<h1>{{ head.text }}</h1>
<a href="#"><img src="{{ head.img.url }}"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

1. List item
   And that show me this:

[image]

Comment: do you have `from Test import settings` in your urls.py or it is just an example import? Replace it with django's lazy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added an media url entry to project level urls file?

If the image file is showing 404 response, You can do it like this:

```
# myproject/urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```